# Convert Oracle BPEL forEach to Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, oracle-soa, oracle-bpm-suite

In a migration from Oracle BPEL to Apache Camel, which particular considerations should I have for migrating forEach (Oracle) to loop (Camel)?

this one is the BPEL file. How can I convert that to use Apache Camel loop? I am finding trouble in using loop tag from Apache Camel.

```
  <sequence name="main">

    <!-- Receive input from requestor. (Note: This maps to operation defined in ExemploForBPELProcess.wsdl) -->
    <receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="exemploforbpelprocess_client" portType="client:ExemploForBPELProcess" operation="process" variable="inputVariable" createInstance="yes"/>

    <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
    <assign name="olaAssign">
      <copy>
        <from>'Hi:'</from>
        <to>$outputVariable.payload/client:result</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <forEach parallel="no" counterName="ForEachNomeCounter" name="ForEachNome">
      <startCounterValue>1</startCounterValue>
      <finalCounterValue>ora:countNodes('inputVariable','payload','client:nome')</finalCounterValue>
      <scope name="Scope" exitOnStandardFault="no">
        <assign name="NomeAssign">
          <copy>
            <from>concat($outputVariable.payload/client:result,' ',$inputVariable.payload/client:nome[$ForEachNomeCounter],',')</from>
            <to>$outputVariable.payload/client:result</to>
          </copy>
        </assign>
      </scope>
    </forEach>
    <assign name="FimAssign">
      <copy>
        <from>concat($outputVariable.payload/client:result,' all fine?')</from>
        <to>$outputVariable.payload/client:result</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <reply name="replyOutput" partnerLink="exemploforbpelprocess_client" portType="client:ExemploForBPELProcess" operation="process" variable="outputVariable"/>
  </sequence>
</process>
```

Comment: Please show your code, at least what you want to convert that causes the issue

Comment: added code @NicolasFilotto - could you please help?